# Image Rotation in javascript

Tags: javascript, rotation

I have a conceptual issue.

I have a set of images on the server and i am generating a random rotation angle. the user will download the images and rotate them using the random angle. the user will rotate the images and then i want to know if the angle was the same as it was before rotating it i.e. 0.

I am using HTML5 and fabric.js.

Any ideas how i can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let's start off with what *you* have tried, and go from there.

Comment: Begin by perusing the "Related" links to the right. --->

Comment: But you say that you, i.e. your server is generating the angle. Can't you just check if it's zero?